# Convert Faceboook Meta cUrl to PHP

Tags: php, curl

How can I convert the following cUrl to PHP.

```
curl -i -X POST \
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "TO_PHONE_NUMBER", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "hello_world", "language": { "code": "en_US" } } }'
```

I want to use the standard `curl_init` and `curl_exec` to execute the url function.

So far, I have tried the following.

```
$endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/".$whatsappPhoneNumberId."/messages";
            
            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

            $bodyFields = [
                "messaging_product" => "whatsapp",
                "to" => "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                "type" => "template",
                "template" => [
                    "name" => "hello_world",
                    "languauge" => [
                        "code" => 'en_US',
                    ]
                ],
            ];

            $cUrl = curl_init($endpoint);
            curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($bodyFields));
            
            $response = curl_exec($cUrl);
            curl_close($cUrl);
```

I need to add the access token, and also getting an error as follows when I call the endpoint

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Unexpected key \"languauge\" on param \"template\".","type":"OAuthException","code":100 }}
```

Comment: languauge ( in your php code ) is not language, you have a typo

Comment: Thank you @hassan. Didn't notice the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add access token you should simply add another header:

```php
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken;
```

---

*also getting an error as follows when I call the endpoint* - spelling error in word `languauge`. Should be `language`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked out. P.s Didn't notice the typo